# How to set date collection as a data source in AngularJs UI grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

> I need to display only a Date Collection object as a data source in my UI Grid.
>
> > Do I need to define a `field` under `ColumnDefs` in this case? Also, I need to include a column to `delete` that particular row, in this case `Delete the current Date object`.

How can I accomplish this? Below is my code

```
editor.mySeasonBreaks = {            
        data: "editor.mySeasons",
        columnDefs:

       [{ field: "????", visible: true, displayName: "Season Break" },
        {
            name: 'delete',
            displayName: "", 
            cellTemplate: "<button ng-click="editor.delete(row.entity)" />"
        }]
    };
```

In the above code, `editor.mySeasons` is just a date array object.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object-array with your dates and define the columns as needed. This way you got more control and its easy to adjust/expand.

Now for your row-deletion I created [a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKH2ED2lgYVFk2L3Ecn7?p=preview) thats showcases a possible solution.

As you suggest you need to add a cellTemplate that references your delete-function

```
cellTemplate: "<button ng-click=\"grid.appScope.delete(row)\">DELETE ROW</button>"
```

To access that function, you need to add it to your gridDefinition and ther property is called `appScopeProvider`

Possible setup would be

```
appScopeProvider: {
  delete : function(row) {
    editor.mySeasons.forEach(function(entry, index){
      if(entry.myDate === row.entity.myDate) {
        editor.mySeasons.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended scenario, but you can use something like this:

```
$scope.myData=['2015-22-07', '2017-10-08', '2020-17-02'];
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  columnDefs: [
    {
      displayName: 'Date Array',
      cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText ng-class="col.colIndex()">{{row.entity}}</div>'
    }
  ]
};
```

You can test it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qYmnGZWUba1HwOqeuuzm?p=preview).

There are issues with sorting and probably something else.

It's better IMO to translate your array of dates to array of objects:

```
var res = [];
myData.forEach(function(el){
    res.push({date: el});
});
```

Then specify column as usual:

```
{ field: 'date', visible: true, displayName: 'Season Break' }
```